# iOS SDK: Setting a variable in a second view controller - pushViewController

Tags: ios, variables, view, pushviewcontroller

I have made a pageView and each of the pages has a button. When i am pushing to a new view controller how can a pass in a variable. I have done this with android using intent.putExtra().

Here is my code in ios:

```
- (IBAction)openButton:(id)sender {
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
// i have tried: vc.magazine = @"Lifestyle"; but is saying property not found in ViewController
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];

}
```

Here is the variable in the second view controller header file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
NSString *magazine;

}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *magazine;
@end
```

Thanks in advanced, if you have questions please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix, i have changed 'UIViewController' to ViewController then i could do

```
vc.magazine = @"Lifestyle";
```

Thanks anyways.